# What is the location argument of GCP workload identity pools

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, workload-identity

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/workload-identity-pools/create):

an example of creating an identity pool would be

> gcloud iam workload-identity-pools create my-workload-identity-pool --location="global" --display-name="My workload pool" --description="My workload pool description" --disabled

What does the location global mean? What is the purpose of this argument? It is apparently not a location like us-central1 but a logical location.

Which values are available? I don't find any good documentation on this so i am asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `gcloud iam workload-identity-pools create` command you mentioned ultimately calls the API method [projects.locations.workloadIdentityPools.create](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.workloadIdentityPools/create) which states that the only supported location is `global`. This makes sense since `workload-identity-pools` is a feature of the IAM (Identity and Access Management) service, which is a [global product](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations#global-products) replicated across regions.

Now as per why this argument is required in the gcloud command while it isn't even asked in the corresponding [Cloud Console form](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/configuring-workload-identity-federation#console), this seems to be a design decision but in any case the only option is indeed `global`.